# Loading script from HTTP is automatically converted to HTTPS for some users

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load socket.io using the following code:

```
<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

However some users have reported the following error to me:

```
Failed to load https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Is this an automatic security setting on modern browsers? And if so can it be disabled?

Comment: server `cdn.socket.io` redirecting to ssl protocol, you can't do anything about this, use another server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem is not your fault!

Accessing that link in my browser fails as well, and inspecting the unsuccessful request shows that the following header was set:

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

This tells the browser to "upgrade" all `http://` URLs to `https://`, which seems to mirror the error your users are reporting.

`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` indicates that the SSL certificate for https://cdn.socket.io/ is incorrectly configured and thus the browser (rightly) assumes the worst, and chooses not to trust data served from that domain over the secure protocol. When the domain is configured to "upgrade" insecure requests to secure ones, and secure requests are rejected by the browser, it becomes clear why there is no way to access the content correctly at either URL.

I would contact the administrators of the website and inform them of the problem, or just simply switch to another CDN like [Chris Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7080032/chris-chen) suggested:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js"></‌​script>
```

Comment: Thats good to know. I will contact them and for the time being I will host the script on my server.

Comment: Glad to help! And no need to host it on your own server; see the attached link above.

Comment: That link gives me a 404 Error when trying to load it

Comment: Should be fixed . . . there appeared to be an issue with SO formatting the pasted link strangely.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the users who are experiencing that error are hitting the https version of your page. Best way to deal with this issue is by changing your code to:

```
<script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

Or

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

The former is preferable (because it is faster for http users) unless you are working with an .html or .htm page and want to open it without a web server.

Comment: That's not the case it seems. It looks like cdn.socket.io have reconfigured their servers to redirect all http request to https but they haven't actually configured https on their server (they just did a rewrite to change "http" to "https"). It's socket.io's fault

Answer (score 0):

The link is not working at all from anywhere. Is it a private link that require certification?

If you just want socket.io.js, use link from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io